# error in the statement (Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)

Tags: android

this is the utility java class to check which version of android is being used....but there is an error in the statement  @interface TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)...what may be the possible reasons and how can I remove it??

```
package com.example.ishan.complainbox;

/**
 * Created by ishan on 11/04/2017.
*/
import android.os.Build;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
 public class Utility {
 public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;

 @interface TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
 public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
  {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
  Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 
  PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if 
(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((MainActivity) context, 
Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is 
necessary");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((MainActivity) 
context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 
MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else
                {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((MainActivity) context, 
new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 
MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else
        {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please include the logcat output.

Comment: Just try replacing `@interface TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)` with `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)`

Comment: thankyou mr narendra!!